# Is onDestroy() also indicate to the Garbage collector that the Activity object should be collected?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, garbage-collection, ondestroy

I'm trying to understand, if a class that extends **Activity** has attributes, and while working with the application those attributes are being set (values are different from null), if the **Activity** is being destroyed (let's say the user press on back button and left the application), is the **Activity** object is being collected by the GC? Are the values that were set for those attributes are still have the values they had before the **onDestroy()**

Comment: It's a life cycle callback, you essentially get informed that this activity instance is destroyed and will no longer serve as your application component (whether it's picked up by GC is out of your control and irrelevant). If user relaunches your app another instance will be created and it will indeed have all fields set to defaults (or null as you say) - it's a bit confusing for newcomers but to carry over data from destroyed instance you have to use things like `savedInstanceState`, `ViewModel`s, preferences or a database depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation here: [onDestroy()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onDestroy())

Comment: Even if the link can answer, can you include the explaination from the link, to don't have a link-only answer ?